# Detecting which Button was pressed in a flextable

Tags: java, gwt, flextable

I have a flextable, and in that table I have a column where each row has a button to remove that row. How can I get the index of that row so that I can remove it. I only need to get a index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A solution: 

FlexTable myTable = new FlexTable();
myTable.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Cell cell = myTable.getCellForEvent(event);
    int receiverRowIndex = cell.getRowIndex();
}
});
```